# How to set black region in one frame to pixels of another frame using openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to set the black region of one frame to be the value of the image in another frame. You can see both images below. Is there are a way of replacing the black region with the image in OpenCV?

Colour Image

[image]

Image to merge

[image]

**EDIT**
After applying suggested method: 
[Image after applying Miki's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCv6X.png)

Comment: What data from color image you want to put in the black image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `copyTo`, with a proper mask. For this, you need that both images have the same size. Here I used `resize`, but you can select an appropriate ROI as well.

To get the mask, I used `inRange` since it allows to work with 3 channels images. You can also convert to grayscale (`cvtColor(..., COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`) and use `threshold`. The result is:

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Read images
    Mat3b img1 = imread("path_to_street_image");
    Mat3b img2 = imread("path_to_mask_image");

    // Must have equal size
    resize(img1, img1, img2.size());

    // Get the mask for black part
    Mat1b mask;
    inRange(img2, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(0,0,0), mask);

    // Copy img1 into img2, according to the mask
    img1.copyTo(img2, mask);

    // Show results
    imshow("Result", img2);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi for some reason I'm not getting the same result as you, I've added an edit to show the image I get using the same code.

Comment: It seems you're copying to another image, not "img2"

Comment: I've added my full code, the show results section of your code should be img2? right? , When I run your code in  separate test file I get the right image, however within my application it's not working I've attached the full code above, any idea why it's not working? excuse the messy code for now.

Comment: Yes, `img2`, it was a typo.

Comment: I can't go through all your code. Please make a [mcve]. Also, probably the `converTo` immediately before the mask code doesn't do what you expect, but I cannot say it for sure..

Comment: Ah don't worry thanks for your help. Turns out one of my images was of type CV_8UC1 whilst the other was CV_8UC3 which was preventing it being copied.